# transforming large imports of data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on the best way to import a long csv table and then transform into two tables for efficiency.
This is a very scaled down version but for this purpose suits:

each row is a unique record but the first three columns consist of very consistant data over a large amount of rows.

I figured the best way to manage this data was to build two tables:

The first being an auto increment id field and a group by of the first three columns.

This gives a nice compact table of the main groupings of my data.

The second table was to be every row but instead of holding all the repeated data I hold only the variable data columns d, e and f along with the autoincrement id field i generate when importing into the first table.

My question is really how do I get the id from the first table - is my only way to requery that table to find the id and then do the insert into the second table?

```
a,b,c,d,e,f

09/02/2013,A1,1,18503112043123,11,2.1219
09/02/2013,A1,1,44102576116476,73,14.0817
09/02/2013,A1,1,66918345446536,134,25.8486
09/02/2013,A1,2,62009507978229,10,1.929
09/02/2013,A1,2,92278593945574,55,10.6095
09/02/2013,B1,1,50474606002324,90,17.361
09/02/2013,B1,1,59697581427675,7,1.3503
09/02/2013,B1,1,86298530583467,51,9.8379
09/02/2013,B1,2,34885481077847,80,15.432
09/02/2013,B1,2,25479347211047,164,31.6356
09/02/2013,B1,3,56270556524425,6,1.1574
09/02/2013,C1,1,57680166803098,24,4.6296
09/02/2013,C1,1,72778510788287,77,14.8533
09/02/2013,C1,1,26084111080146,140,27.006
09/02/2013,C1,1,31435464483578,361,65.5937
09/02/2013,C1,2,29457756254473,492,89.3964
09/02/2013,C1,2,68414218104066,293,53.2381
```

EDIT

I have two queries in mind:
1: My parent table which has an auto increment
    insert into parent_table
    select null,a,b,c
    from table
    group by a,b,c

1. My child table which is all my rows of data but includes corresponding auto increment id from the parent table.

I dont understand how to pull the id back again without doing a query back to the parent table as i input the data into the child table

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) or [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php) to retrieve the

> auto generated id used in the last query.

Just do the insert and then fetch the id

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("insert into first_table (a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)");
$sth->execute(array('2013-02-09', 'A1', 1));
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

There is also the MySQL [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). You could test

```
insert into second_table (first_table_id, d, e, f) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...)
```

but I have never tried this myself.

Comment: OK - so my best method is to do this through php not in mysql directly. 
This means looping over the data row by row doesn't it

Comment: @user1479891 There is also `last_insert_id()` from mysql, please see updated answer.